# How to link each Marker with it's own infoWindow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As you can see, I'm iterating into a json object containing the markers info, like this:

( I'm also using the infobox plugin, but it's not relevant for the question)

```
function drawAirports() {
    var markers = [];

    if ( markers != undefined) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
        markers.length = 0;
    }

    var json = [
        {"id":8585885,"airport":"airport name", "lat" : "1.3", "long" : "1.33"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 1", "lat" : "-1.3", "long" : "1.33"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 2", "lat" : "42.5000", "long" : "1.5000"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 3", "lat" : "24.0000", "long" : "54.0000"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 4", "lat" : "17.0500", "long" : "-61.8000"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 5", "lat" : "18.2500", "long" : "-63.1667"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 6", "lat" : "24.0000", "long" : "54.0000"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 7", "lat" : "41.0000", "long" : "20.0000"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 8", "lat" : "40.0000", "long" : "45.0000"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 9", "lat" : "12.2500", "long" : "-68.7500"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 10", "lat" : "-12.5000", "long" : "18.5000"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 11", "lat" : "35.0000", "long" : "105.0000"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 12", "lat" : "-90.0000", "long" : "0.0000"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 13", "lat" : "34.0000", "long" : "-64.0000"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 14", "lat" : "-14.3333", "long" : "-170.0000"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 15", "lat" : "47.3333", "long" : "13.3333"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 16", "lat" : "-27.0000", "long" : "133.0000"},
        {"id":8585886,"airport":"airport name 17", "lat" : "12.5000", "long" : "-69.9667"}
    ];

    var airports = eval(json);

    for (var i = 0; i < airports.length; i++) {

        var airport = airports[i];

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(airport.lat, airport.long),
            map: map,
            title: airport.airport,
            icon: 'img/gmaps/marker.png',
            visible: true
        });

        infobox = new InfoBox({
             content: '<h3>'+airport.airport+'</h3><a class="info" href="">Información</a><a class="bags" href="">Equipajes</a>',
             disableAutoPan: false,
             maxWidth: 150,
             pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-212, -150),
             zIndex: null,
             boxStyle: {
                width: "280px"
            },
            closeBoxMargin: "0",
            closeBoxURL: "img/gmaps/close.png",
            infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infobox.open(map, this);
            map.panTo(loc);
        });

        markers.push(marker);                       
    }
}
```

My problem is that each marker open the last ( number 17 ) infowindow,

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your problem is not with Google Maps API utilization, or the library, but with the way you use closures. You have global variable `infobox`, which is fine since you want only one infobox and close any infobox present on map before opening new one, but the way you have it `infobox` always points to the last one created, which is number 17, the last location. Just use Javascript closure and and create the infobox inside the listener code, leveraging the fact `airport` always contains the correct data because of the closure. This should work:

```
function drawAirports() {
  var markers = [];
  var infobox = new InfoBox({
      content: '',
      disableAutoPan: false,
      maxWidth: 150,
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-212, -150),
      zIndex: null,
      boxStyle: {
          width: "280px"
      },
      closeBoxMargin: "0",
      closeBoxURL: "img/gmaps/close.png",
      infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
  });

  if (markers != undefined) {
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          markers[i].setMap(null);
      }
      markers.length = 0;
  }

  var json = [
      {"id": 8585885, "airport": "airport name", "lat": "1.3", "long": "1.33"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 1", "lat": "-1.3", "long": "1.33"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 2", "lat": "42.5000", "long": "1.5000"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 3", "lat": "24.0000", "long": "54.0000"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 4", "lat": "17.0500", "long": "-61.8000"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 5", "lat": "18.2500", "long": "-63.1667"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 6", "lat": "24.0000", "long": "54.0000"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 7", "lat": "41.0000", "long": "20.0000"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 8", "lat": "40.0000", "long": "45.0000"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 9", "lat": "12.2500", "long": "-68.7500"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 10", "lat": "-12.5000", "long": "18.5000"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 11", "lat": "35.0000", "long": "105.0000"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 12", "lat": "-90.0000", "long": "0.0000"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 13", "lat": "34.0000", "long": "-64.0000"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 14", "lat": "-14.3333", "long": "-170.0000"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 15", "lat": "47.3333", "long": "13.3333"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 16", "lat": "-27.0000", "long": "133.0000"},
      {"id": 8585886, "airport": "airport name 17", "lat": "12.5000", "long": "-69.9667"}
  ];

  var airports = eval(json);

  for (var i = 0; i < airports.length; i++) {
      (function (airport) {

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(airport.lat, airport.long),
              map: map,
              title: airport.airport,
              icon: 'img/gmaps/marker.png',
              visible: true
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
              infobox.setContent('<h3>' + airport.airport + '</h3><a class="info" href="">Información</a><a class="bags" href="">Equipajes</a>');
              infobox.open(map, this);
          });

          markers.push(marker);
      })(airports[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to know more about closures: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Comment: Still this is probably not the way you should do it... You better create only one instance of the InfoBox and use the `setContent` method to update the contents.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I have updated my answer according to you suggestion, but I must say there are plenty other improvements which can be done. Same with most of code examples here on SO. I have also included infobox in the scope of the function so the global scope is not polluted. But I still think It's really petty to pick up on some detail and down-vote, considering that my answer was demonstrating wrong use of scope not the most feasible way to achieve what the user wanted.

Comment: And now it's a better answer. And I removed my downvote. And I think it's a pretty good way to push people to update/improve their answers ;-)

Comment: Btw. with only one InfoBox, I don't think you need the `if(infobox) infobox.close();` line if it works the same way than the standard infowindow.

Comment: @MrUpsidown The close() method only removes listeners and sets map to null. So yes, it seems it's not needed. I have tested locally and it works without it. I have updated the answer, thanks.