# Google Map info window is only showing on one marker in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am developing a Website that offers location based service. So I am integrating my website with Google Map API using JavaScript. Then I import the data to Map and show each item as marker on Map. Importing and showing data as markers on map is working fine.

But I am having a problem with showing info window for each marker on map. The problem is I got two markers on my map, but when I click on whatever item, info window is always showing on the same item. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, I clicked on the marker on the right, but info window is showing on the different item.

This is my full JavaScript for map:

```
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        var lat = $('.region-latitude').val();
        var long = $('.region-longitude').val();
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        });

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = $('.map-items-url').val();
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    window.items_callback = function (results) {

        for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
            var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
            var itemMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                title: results.features[i].name
            });

            var contentString = '<h3>' + results.features[i].name + '</h3>';

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            });

            itemMarker.addListener('click', function () {
                infowindow.open(map, itemMarker);
            });

        }
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)
```

What is wrong with my code? How can I show different info window for each marker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a scope problem. At the moment when `click` handler is activated, the `itemMarker` points to the last added marker as well as `infowindow` points to last info window created. That's why it always shows only over last added marker. You have to create a scope which encapsulates these variables.

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
   (function(index){
        var coords = results.features[index].geometry.coordinates;

        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
        var itemMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            title: results.features[index].name
        });

        var contentString = '<h3>' + results.features[index].name + '</h3>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        itemMarker.addListener('click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, itemMarker);
        });

    })(i);
}
```

For more information check this [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112677/how-to-link-each-marker-with-its-own-infowindow) and also [this SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294122/how-to-know-which-marker-was-clicked-googlemaps). Also [this](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/interview-questions) is a good post on the scopes matter.

Comment: Thanks so much. Perfect answer.